# how to run docker container with external application properties file?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, containers, volume

How to run docker containers with external application properties files? & how to add properties file into the docker volume ? how to mount the volume with another container?.

Answer (score 1):

**This 2 links contain all you want.**
Check is out first [How to use external application properties file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files)

Then, learn how to manage dockerFile [How to initial docker and do volume](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/)

After that, just include the properties file in docker image or mount volumn of your local and execute the application with a bit extra command.

Answer (score 0):

copy external application.properties file into the location.
Now dockerfile command:

cmd ["java","-jar","-Dspring.config.location=file:./application.properties","myapp.jar"]